# copy object Inheritance Mapping doctrine2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

i have the following entity:

```
/**    
* @ORM\Table(name="event")
* @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
* @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="eventtype", type="integer")
* @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({1 = "eventClub", 2 = "eventLive", 3 = "eventBar", 4 = "eventGeneric" }) 
*/
class P1event extends AbstractEntity {

/**
 *
 * @var List[] $lists
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="List", mappedBy="fkevent", cascade={"persist", "merge"})"
 */
private $lists;
```

A user should have the possibility to change the eventtype via a form. By changing the evetntype, i must create a new Object becaus of my table inheritance ([doctrine doc](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#single-table-inheritance)).

I have no idea how i can change the lists of the copied event to the new event inside one transaction. Has anybody an idea how to handle it correctly? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

In a similar situation, I just passed GET parameter type, then in the controller created an object of the desired type and transferred it to the form. If I understand your question correctly.

Answer (score 0):

After created a new event object, call

```
$eventY->setLists($eventX->getLists());
```

doen't work ?